# Android conversion emoji

Tags: android, emoji

I have some emoji that I am parsing from server like   (converted well) and this one  (not working)

I receive different results on different devices so If you can suggest some solutions this will be helpfull a lot

Server response :

```
{
"text": "I'm broke ",
"destination": "Iam_broke"
```

Screenshot :

- [image]

Thank you

Comment: You should post some code examples and server response to let us understand what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution , tried with the latest Android version and all emoji working fine , for any one facing this problem you will need to use the EmojiCompat support library, so your your app users do not need to wait for Android OS updates to get the latest emoji

Read more : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/emoji-compat.html